# Create dynamic return depending on logic behind in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner at dart/flutter. Is it possible to create a function or ... like this in dart? Seriously, I don't know what it is called! Let me explain what I wanted. Let say my app have 2 account type "premium" & "free". I want to create a widget or callback function or whatever which can return Type depending on my app account type (this calculated in underlying):

**- Use in widget**

```
Container(
        child: AccountType.when(
          (premium) => PremiumWidget(),
          (free) => FreeWidget(),
        ),
      ),
```

For checking account type is done in underlying.

**- Use in function**

```
IconButton(
        onPressed: AccountType.when(
          (premium) => () {},
          (free) => () {}
        ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
      ),
```

How can I achieve that? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: are you asking about callback function for thoes IconButton ?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, I want to return it dynamically like generics class for example. T when<T>(...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use enum and if/else for that. First create the AccountType enum:

```
enum AccountType {
  premium,
  free,
}
```

Usage in widget:

```
Container(
          child: (accountType == AccountType.premium ? 
          PremiumWidget() : 
          FreeWidget())
      );
```

Usage in function:

```
IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (accountType == AccountType.premium) {
            // do something for premium account
          } else {
            // do something for free account
          }
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
      );
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. This worked as expected, But I want to do those logic behind like AsynValue in freeze package as an example